# Node js with express how to enable cache for static files

Tags: node.js, express, browser-cache, http-status-code-304, expires-header

I have tried all the possibilities. Following are my response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Expires: Sun, 20 Dec 2015 03:53:42 GMT

Accept-Ranges: bytes

Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800

Last-Modified: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 15:49:21 GMT

Etag: W/"25571-15163623fb3"

Content-Type: image/png

Content-Length: 152945

Date: Sun, 13 Dec 2015 03:53:42 GMT

Connection: keep-alive
```

But still it's not returning 304 status. If I refresh command refresh in Firefox it's downloading that image again with 200 response code. I don't want that if user click command refresh it's should return 304 status. instead of downloading new file it should take it from browser cache.

Following is my nodejs code

```
var expireTime = 604800000;


app.all('/css*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Expires', new Date(Date.now() + expireTime).toUTCString());
  next();
});   


app.use('/css',express.static(conf.nodePath + 'css',{ maxAge: expireTime}));
```

Can anyone guide me how to enable perfect cache. Thanks in advance..

Comment: maybe try to use `.sendFile` in the route that you are setting the header and not calling `next()`. Maybe the other route overwrites the header when you pass the request to it.

Comment: You don't need to set expire data manually , Just try "var oneHour = 3600000;app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'),{maxAge:oneHour}))';  When you finish code, try to delete all cache file from your browser, and test again

Comment: Because static module based on server-static, you can get lots information from its docs https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static